# jQuery function works in partial but not show

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have jquery code that counts the current rows in a table (and does some arithmetic) and adds them to a column. I've used this script in my `_form/_partial` and it works great. However, when I use the same script inside my `show.html.erb` (to setup the same table again) it does not work.

Here is my `_form`

```
<table id="mytable">
    <th>RowNumber</th>
    <th>header2</th>
    <th>header3</th>
    <th>header4</th>  
        <%= f.nested_fields_for :partial do |f|
          render 'partial', f: f
        end -%> 
         <caption align = "bottom"><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Field", f, :manual_iops %></caption>
</table>
```

> _partial.html.erb

```
<tr>
 <td> 
   <!-- Nothing Goes Here -->   
 </td>

 <td>
  <%= f.text_field :data1 %>
 </td>

 <td>
  <%= f.text_field :data2 %>
 </td>

  <td>
  <%= f.text_field :data3 %>
 </td>

</tr>

  <script>
   $('tr').each(function(){
     var index= $('#mytable').children('tr').index($(this))
     if(index == 0){
       var position= 5;
     }
     if(index == 1){
       var position = 10;
     }
     if(index == 2){
       var position = 15;
     }
     if(index == 3){
       var position = 20;
     }
     if(index > 3){
       var position = (index-1)*10
     }
     $(this).children('td').first().html(position);
  })
</script>
```

Now here is what I'm trying in my show:

> show.html.erb

```
<table id="mytable">
  <th>RowNumber</th>
  <th>header1</th>
  <th>header2</th>
  <th>header3</th>
     <% @data_sheet.partials.each do |c| %>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><%= c.data1 %></td>
      <td><%= c.data2 %></td>
      <td><%= c.data3 %></td>
    </tr>
  <script>
     $('tr').each(function(){
         var index= $('#mytable').children('tr').index($(this))
         if(index == 0){
               var position= 5;
         }
         if(index == 1){
               var position = 10;
         }
         if(index == 2){
               var position = 15;
         }
         if(index == 3){
               var position = 20;
         }
         if(index > 3){
               var position = (index-1)*10
         }
        $(this).children('td').first().html(position);
    })
  </script>
     <% end %>
</table>
```

Here is an image of how my `_form` looks, you can see the first column has values: `5, 10, 15, 20`, due to my script in `partial.html.erb` counting the rows and doing some + and *:
[image]

And here is my `show.html.erb`, which shows an empty column(it should be filled `5,10,15,20`) due my issue.  I am running the same script here from my partial:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong in this situation?  The only thing I see different is my loop and the fact I am not rendering a partial, but I see no reason why this should effect my javascript.  I'm really banging my head against the wall by this.

Comment: What is not working? Can you describe the actual problem?

Comment: Yeah, I'll post an image

Comment: Updated, with some images.  Hope that makes thing clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if you want to do this with ruby it's easy:

```
<table id="mytable">
  <th>RowNumber</th>
  <th>header1</th>
  <th>header2</th>
  <th>header3</th>

  <% @count = 5 %>  
  <% @data_sheet.partials.each do |c| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= @count %></td>
      <td><%= c.data1 %></td>
      <td><%= c.data2 %></td>
      <td><%= c.data3 %></td>
    </tr>
  <% if @count >= 20 %>
    <% @count = @count + 10 %>
  <% else %> 
    <% @count = @count + 5 %>  
  <% end %>
</table>
```

You can rewrite the if and statement as:

```
<% @count >= 20 ? (@count = @count + 10) : (@count = @count + 5) %>
```

Comment: Thank you sir for sticking with me through this question

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Wow, I didn't realize you were looping that script. Are you doing that on purpose?  Try changing your show to:

```
<table id="mytable">
  <th>RowNumber</th>
  <th>header1</th>
  <th>header2</th>
  <th>header3</th>
     <% @data_sheet.partials.each do |c| %>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><%= c.data1 %></td>
      <td><%= c.data2 %></td>
      <td><%= c.data3 %></td>
    </tr>
     <% end %>
</table>  

  <% content_for :scripts do %>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $('tr').each(function(){
             var index= $('#mytable').children('tr').index($(this))
             if(index == 0){
                   var position= 5;
             }
             if(index == 1){
                   var position = 10;
             }
             if(index == 2){
                   var position = 15;
             }
             if(index == 3){
                   var position = 20;
             }
             if(index > 3){
                   var position = (index-1)*10
             }
            $(this).children('td').first().html(position);
        });
      });
      </script>
   <% end %>
```

**Old answer**

The main problem is probably the script being called before the document is ready, so try wrapping in a document.ready function. Also for added precaution put it just before the `</body>` tag.

Try putting `<%= yield :scripts %>` just before your `</body>` tag in your application.html.erb

Now in your partial put:

```
  <% content_for :scripts do %>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
         $('tr').each(function(){
             var index= $('#mytable').children('tr').index($(this))
             if(index == 0){
                   var position= 5;
             }
             if(index == 1){
                   var position = 10;
             }
             if(index == 2){
                   var position = 15;
             }
             if(index == 3){
                   var position = 20;
             }
             if(index > 3){
                   var position = (index-1)*10
             }
            $(this).children('td').first().html(position);
        });
      });
      </script>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: unfortunately, there is no change :(

Comment: Wait why are you calling this script inside the ruby loop?

Comment: That was just the particular way I set it at that moment.  I've tried it outside the loop but it still has not work.

Comment: Did you do <%= yield :scripts %> in your application.html?   Otherwise leave out the content_for tag

Comment: also are you seeing any js errors in your chrome console, etc?

Comment: I've done as you have suggested.  No errors that I could see.  I have a very odd problem...

Comment: Maybe you should just use ruby to create the numbers you need. It's probably the most sensible thing, if possible for you

Comment: Probably, but how can I do this?  I couldn't think of a way.  Still pretty new to rails and ruby